# Windows 10 alt+end outputs a smiley

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, alt

I use Resharper in VS2017 every day and noticed this morning when pressing `alt+end` that a smiley now appears.  This is me pressing `alt+end`: ☺

I then noticed that `alt+` some others also produce odd characters:

`alt+pgup`: ○
`alt+pgdn`: ♥

This is driving me insane.  Any ideas?  I've checked the keyboard and language/regional settings but nothing appears amiss.

Comment: Just to add: it seems to be an intermittent problem.  It had now gone away.  And yes, I *did* reboot :) --- anyway, I'm keeping an eye out and I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: I've started having this happen too but it's not going away for me. I'm also in VS2017 and using R#. Did you ever figure out if you did anything to make it go away?

Comment: @N Jones: Unfortunately I never figured out why it was happening.  My machine had to be rebuilt after replacing the HDD with a SSD and after that it didn't ever happen again.  What I did notice was that it seemed to be somehow "activated" after the first odd combination of keys and then I was stuck with it.  I came across a low level keyboard hook (driver) but our policy at work (being a work machine) did not allow installing the driver.  I cannot remember the name but perhaps a search could help.  It would show all programs linked to the hook.  Was hoping to find the culprit that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the smiley like this:

1. In ReSharper Options/Environment/Keyboard I switched to None and applied the scheme
2. In the same place, I switched back to Visual Studio Scheme and applied and saved

When I tried Alt+End it was working again. Maybe you will need to map some shortcuts again but it's a small price to pay to get rid of the smiley.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [ASCII characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0).

> To insert an ASCII character, press and hold down ALT while typing the character code. For example, to insert the degree (º) symbol, press and hold down ALT while typing 0176 on the numeric keypad.

Here are some more examples:

- ALT + 4: ♦
- ALT + 85: U
- ALT + 104: h

Comment: In my case I'm not after any characters :) --- I literally press `alt+end` to navigate to "Derived Symbols" in VS2017 using Resharper and the smiley appears.  I tested in Notepad++ and Word and the same thing happens.

Comment: Do I get that you don't want this behaviour? I suggest you change the title of your question to "How do I stop ALT+end outputting a smiley in Visual Studio?". I am not a VS user so I am not that experienced with its controls, but this should be somewhere in settings.